# floor of double(time_t)

Tags: c, math, floor

I cannot understand why this throws *undefined reference to `floor'*":

```
double curr_time = (double)time(NULL);
return floor(curr_time);
```

Hasn't it been casted to double, which is what *floor* receives?

Comment: Did you link against the math library (e.g., -lm for gcc)?  "Undefined reference" errors usually indicate that the linker can't find the object code for something.

Comment: Undefined reference errors come from the linker, the missing header would should be a compile time error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You possibly have run in to the infamous `-lm` problem: Compile as:

```
gcc yourfile.c -o out -lm
```

This is C [FAQ 14.3](http://c-faq.com/fp/libm.html) item as well.

Comment: Library linking flags should go after sources and object files, btw.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe because you don't link with the math library? The error has nothing to do with casts and data types, btw.

Comment: What I do not understand is why, without linking with the math library either, things like floor(1.2) _do_ worked. That is why I thought the error was related to the data type.

Comment: @plok: Maybe it worked, because you were on a different system? Sometimes, the library is linked by default.

Comment: @Lucas: it was on the same system, without modifying anything. I just tried with a simpler statement when the error was thrown and saw that floor(1.2) worked. Is it possible that the result is being calculated by gcc at compile time?

Comment: @plok: Yes.  GCC will evaluate `floor(1.2)` at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to link explicitly to the library. On an UNIX-like system this would typically be "/usr/lib/libm.a". The C standard library should be linked by default, but the math library is, depending on your system, not linked and you may have to link explicitly. (e.g. on Mac OS X it is also linked by default on my ubuntu system it is not).

Note that this has nothing to do with your include path. If you are on something UNIX-like you will probably find the header with the prototype declaration under "/usr/include/math.h", where your compiler will always look for headers.

If you are using gcc, you can either link directly with:

```
gcc yourfile.c /usr/lib/libm.a -o out
```

or with "-l**nameroflibrary**" like this:

```
gcc yourfile.c -lm -o out
```

this will look for a library in the same directory as the C standard library with the name "lib**nameoflibrary**.a"